# How can I assign the contents of a form text field?

Tags: javascript

How can I assign the contents of a form text field called "username" which is in the first form in a document to a variable called "thename"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
var thename=document.getElementById(<textFieldId>).value
```